# Django-allauth - Error Accessing FB User Profile - Max Retries Exceeded

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm trying to finish the setup of django-allauth for my site (in development).

Using Django==1.6.5 and django-allauth==0.17.0.

After following the documentation, I have been able to get the FB dialog. When I click OK, it hangs on `localhost:8000/accounts/facebook/login/token/` for about 2 minutes, before returning with an error. The console is showing:
Error accessing FB user profile

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/amir/claudius/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/socialaccount/providers/facebook/views.py", line 73, in login_by_token
        login = fb_complete_login(request, app, token)
      File "/home/amir/claudius/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/socialaccount/providers/facebook/views.py", line 26, in fb_complete_login
        params={'access_token': token.token})
      File "/home/amir/claudius/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
        return request('get', url, **kwargs)
      File "/home/amir/claudius/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
        return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
      File "/home/amir/claudius/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 456, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "/home/amir/claudius/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 559, in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "/home/amir/claudius/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 375, in send
        raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='graph.facebook.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /me?access_token=CAAUi8RJCRZAkBAPdHFKhckONnLwjOExZCeVXpW39GZAZBLdD5rTsukQqTPi9KP6neMDxtwdhZAQvmzCS92rxR0rIZCNlzenQ2jHiyANvToy6tOWrOh5ZAYFmJFYeYvbXGNc9fuPIa0hAUqGfPzFtZB0tepoxoO7bpt01izuTYBkmS9NJChXaX9iDZAQlDTDvtLTZBvLesjFtSfwp6RusbArRzH (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable)
[26/Jul/2014 06:14:36] "POST /accounts/facebook/login/token/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1205
```

Anyone knows the cause for this?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @rajasimon. It seems that the issue is that my development machine doesn't have IPv6 enabled. Hope that helps someone out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out that **Facebook Graph API requires IPv6** in [a PHP post by Etienne Rached](http://www.tech-and-dev.com/2012/07/how-to-fix-facebook-connect-error.html), of all places. Tethering through my mobile phone solved it straight away after that for the development process, and this will be a non-issue when our website is deployed.

I hope this will help someone out there.